# Lots of compile errors after Android Launcher Source Code is imported into workspace

Tags: android, launcher, android-2.3-gingerbread

I have task to modify default android gingerbread launcher (android 2.3). I want to download launcher's sources and add functionality according to my task. I have found sources here:

[android Gingerbread launcher sources](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher2.git/+/gingerbread)

I download this and import into workspace as is. As a result I get numerous compile errors (some classes are missing, instance variables are missing, etc). Why? I mean why wouldn't it compile? What should I do to make it compile?

P.S. By the way, when project is imported, used platform as per project settings is not 2.3, so I have to manually set it to 2.3. However, numerous errors still remain.